# spark cassandra maptype selecting only a particular key as column where number of keys are more than 4

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I need to extract out values from map in Cassandra dataframe as columns like
I have a dataframe like

```
 val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
 val rdd  = cc.sql("select * from sams.events where appname = 'test'");
```

Columns in rdd are "appname" as string and "client" as Map
My client in cassandra is a map of map and key like 'platform', 'device' value as 'android' or 'ios'

I need to select only platform key and make it as a column

This is what I did
rdd.registerTempTable("newdf")
var df2 = cc.sql("select appname, client.platform from newdf");

This succeeds but it the platform value is always null. 
My newdf has a map of values.

[Update]
If the cassandra table map column has keys less than 5 then the above works, but if I have number of keys more than or equal to 5 then it does not work and gives me all null. 
This is really strange. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some serious issues with the casandrasqlcontext. This is also one of the issues with the cassandra connector for spark. I am using this version spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.0-M1.jar. I would seriously recommend to people to not use cassandra sql context as its has many issues. Use this instead

val cassDF = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "some_table", "keyspace" -> "myks")).load